# How do I profile an Objective-C program without Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, macos-sierra

I want to create a Release-build of some Objective-C program with Xcode, install it on a very slow machine, generate profiling output, and analyze that output on my machine. I need to do this in order to chase down a specific bug, which only happens on the slow machine.

Machine 1: has Xcode installed. Can compile the program. Is relatively fast. macOS 10.12

Machine 2: doesn't have Xcode installed. Doesn't have Xcode Instruments installed. Will run the program. Should generate profiling output. If I install Xcode on that machine, it will probably slow down to a level that it becomes completely unusable. Is relatively slow. macOS 10.12

The Xcode command "Build for profiling" sounds promising. But.. if I run that "profile build", what has changed? Does it generate profiling output? If yes, where will it be stored? How can I analyze these files?

Any thoughts, or pointers to Apple documentation? I only found the "Instruments User Guide". It tells me how to use Instruments to profile an application.

This is not an iPhone-question. If you are an iPhone-developer and have never worked with macOS-applications, please don't answer ;)

Comment: What do you need to measure?   Memory? I/O? CPU?

Comment: @bbum: I want to measure CPU time and/or real-time/how much time is spent in each function.. I want to see why the program is so slow in some cases.

Comment: Use the `sample` command line tool;   `sample` <PID or name> #secs.

Comment: @bbum, any tips for memory?

Comment: `vm_stat` and `heap`.   You can compare contents of `heap` output over time to see the kinds of accretion that are occurring.